# How can I map Ctrl + semicolon to add a semicolon to the end of the line?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map pressing [ctrl] + [semicolon] in insert mode to move to the end of the line and add a semicolon. It's something I find myself doing a lot after installing the [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.

I tried running this command

```
inoremap <c-;> <esc>A;<esc>
```

but when I try it, it exits me out of insert mode, and goes into command mode. Trying with another modifier `d` yields the same result too.

Can semicolon not be mapped with a modifier?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't read your question carefully, just saw your mapping took you out of the insert mode and the last `<esc>`... my fault.

You want to map `ctrl+;` vim cannot capture the keycode. there are some key combination cannot be mapped in vim. `;` is one of them, another example like `ctrl+=`.

so you may want to choose another mapping.

btw, you can try in insert mode press `ctrl-v` then the keycombination to see if it could be used.

Comment: got the same result :/

Comment: @DeaDEnD also, FYI: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Mapping-ctrl-ctrl-semicolon-td1193549.html

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. I'll try doing something with keyremap4macbook.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your terminal it is possible to set up mappings. For example if you use urxvt, in `~/.Xresources` add:

```
URxvt.keysym.C-semicolon:   \033[;
```

And in `~/.vimrc` add:

```
map  <Esc>[; <C-Semicolon>
map! <Esc>[; <C-Semicolon>
```

Then you should be able to map it like this (not tested):

```
inoremap <c-Semicolon> <Esc>A;<Esc>
```

I use this to map split window movement like this (this works for me):

```
noremap <C-Semicolon> <C-w>l
```